# Error: Invalid Chai property: emit. Did you mean "exist"?

Tags: javascript, solidity, chai

I'm trying to check if my event "ItemListed" is being emit properly.

Here is my solidity code:

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT

pragma solidity ^0.8.7;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/IERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/security/ReentrancyGuard.sol";

error Marketplace__PriceIsZero();

contract Marketplace is ReentrancyGuard {
    address payable public immutable feeAccount;
    uint256 public immutable feePercent;
    uint256 public itemCount;

    struct Item {
        uint256 itemId;
        uint256 tokenId;
        uint256 price;
        IERC721 nft;
        address payable seller;
        bool sold;
    }

    event ItemListed(
        uint256 itemId,
        uint256 tokenId,
        uint256 price,
        address indexed nft,
        address indexed seller
    );

    mapping(uint256 => Item) public items;

    constructor(uint256 _feePercent) {
        feeAccount = payable(msg.sender);
        feePercent = _feePercent;
    }

    function listItem(
        IERC721 _nft,
        uint256 _tokenId,
        uint256 _price
    ) external nonReentrant {
        if (_price <= 0) {
            revert Marketplace__PriceIsZero();
        }
        _nft.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _tokenId);
        items[itemCount] = Item(
            itemCount,
            _tokenId,
            _price,
            _nft,
            payable(msg.sender),
            false
        );
        emit ItemListed(itemCount, _tokenId, _price, address(_nft), msg.sender);
    }
}
```

And here is the test script:

```
const { expect } = require("chai")

const toWei = (num) => ethers.utils.parseEther(num.toString())

describe("NFTMarketplace", function () {
    let feePercent = 1
    let nft, marketplace, deployer, addr1, addr2
    let URI = "SampleURI"
    beforeEach(async () => {
        const NFTFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory("NFT")
        const MarketplaceFactory = await ethers.getContractFactory(
            "Marketplace"
        )
        const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
        deployer = accounts[0]
        addr1 = accounts[1]
        addr2 = accounts[2]
        nft = await NFTFactory.deploy()
        marketplace = await MarketplaceFactory.deploy(feePercent)
    })
    describe("Deployment", function () {
        it("Should track name and symbol of the nft collection", async () => {
            expect(await nft.name(), "DApp NFT")
            expect(await nft.symbol(), "DAPP")
        })
        it("Should feeAccount and feePercent of the marketplace", async () => {
            expect(await marketplace.feeAccount(), deployer.address)
            expect(await marketplace.feePercent(), feePercent)
        })
    })
    describe("Minting NFTs", function () {
        it("Should track each minted NFT", async () => {
            await nft.connect(addr1).mint(URI)
            expect(await nft.tokenCount(), 1)
            expect(await nft.balanceOf(addr1.address), 1)
            expect(await nft.tokenURI(1), URI)

            await nft.connect(addr2).mint(URI)
            expect(await nft.tokenCount(), 2)
            expect(await nft.balanceOf(addr2.address), 1)
            expect(await nft.tokenURI(2), URI)
        })
    })
    describe("Creating items", function () {
        beforeEach(async function () {
            await nft.connect(addr1).mint(URI)
            await nft
                .connect(addr1)
                .setApprovalForAll(marketplace.address, true)
        })
        it("Should track created items, transfer NFT from seller to marketplace and emit an event", async () => {
            await expect(
                marketplace.connect(addr1).listItem(nft.address, 1, toWei(1))
            )
                .to.emit(marketplace, "ItemListed")
                .withArgs(1, 1, toWei(1), nft.address, addr1.address)
        })
    })
})
```

I get the issue at the final "it" (Should track created items, transfer NFT from seller to marketplace and emit an event) on the test script.
Here is the error:

Error: Invalid Chai property: emit. Did you mean "exist"?

Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: That's not part of the core Chai API, have you installed a plugin that provides it like https://www.chaijs.com/plugins/chai-eventemitter2/?

Comment: I just changed it according to this link and it works!! Thanks a lot!!